# Why is this circuit using a branched 5V wire?

Tags: wiring

There is [an article](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/configure-and-read-out-the-raspberry-pi-gas-sensor-mq-x/) for using MQ-135's 5V analogue output with a Raspberry Pi. The picture below is from the article. I only added the [1] mark and pin explanations on it for the sake of question.

At [1], why is the wire branched? The Pi pin is a 5V pin, and it is branched to the MQ-135's port and to the converter's HV. Is this just to save the 5V pins (Pi has two 5V pins)? Or must the two be connected to a branched from a single 5V pin?

[image]

Also, why use wire branching? Couldn't it be like this, without branching?
[image]

Comment: Ya gotta love fritzing.

Comment: I have seen jumper wires with more than two terminals eg: https://www.reichelt.at/continuous-jumper-wire-steckboard-conti-p177332.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is drawn as a conceptual wiring diagram how to do it, like how a schematic represents a device. How to actually realize the conceptual wiring in physical world with physical components is another thing, like how the actual PCB for a device is drawn from the schematics.

Since you don't have T shaped wires, you can do it like you suggest in the second picture and use the protoboard as a junction.